# Fake USB flash drives?

Tags: usb, windows, data-storage

Sometime ago I purchased a USB flash drive from eBay that was advertised as 512GB. But when it arrived it only had like 20GB. I asked for an explanation, but the seller didn't know what happened and gave me a refund.

So I was wondering if sellers who advertise a big capacity are pure scam, or if there's something that the user needs to fix or format to recover all the advertised space.

I already looked online but can't find anything related, but some people complaing about 32GB drives only having 28GB, which is something common.

I'm asking this because I'm currently looking forward to buy a few large capacity USB flash drives for projects and to have another operating system like Linux. But since I'm on a tight budget, I can't waste on buying a bunch to see which ones work or not.

Comment: Hi Momori, sorry you experienced this. As Giacomo said, yes, it's pretty common for these high capacity drives to be fakes—especially on eBay. It's possible it's legitimate but configured wrong (we might be able to provide more info if you give us an actual link to the product), but I'd say it's more likely fake than not. You should probably return the drive to the seller if you're able to.

Comment: Unfortunately, with that said, we don't handle debugging or support for existing hardware on this StackExchange. If you want a recommendation for a replacement drive, feel free to provide your budget and your requirements and we can try to help out.

Comment: FWIW there are integrity testers that will write carefully crafted test data to the entire drive and then check the identical data returns. One I have used for a long time is H2testw by Harald Bögeholz https://www.heise.de/download/product/h2testw-50539

Answer (score 1):

> “So I was wondering if sellers who advertise a big capacity are pure scam…”

Boy howdy! That is *definitely* a scam. A very common scam. Read up here in this article whose title is the not-too-subtle, “[The 2TB Flash Drive Scam: Why “High-Capacity” Flash Drives Are Fakes](https://datarecovery.com/2022/03/the-2tb-flash-drive-scam-why-high-capacity-flash-drives-are-fakes/)”:

> “You’re browsing Amazon or eBay, and you see a great deal: A 2-terabyte (TB) USB thumb drive for about $40. Is it a great bargain — or a dangerous scam?
>
> If you’ve read the headline of this article, you know the answer. However, we’ll make it as clear as possible: **As of March 2022, most 2TB USB drives are scams**. Currently, internet retailers are flooded with fake flash drives, and consumers need to take precautions when ordering storage media online.”

And this one, “[Don't Fall for the Flash Drive Scam!](https://www.instructables.com/Dont-fall-for-the-Flash-Drive-Scam!/)”; bold emphasis is mine:

> “ I recently became aware of a major scam on eBay. Hackers in China are selling flash drives with less memory than they advertise. Users like PikesPeakTraders sell thousands of 'hacked' flash drives from China. **The problem is that the hackers change a log file that makes the flash drive think it has more memory than it does.** When you receive the drive, if you right click and go to properties it will display a larger amount of memory than it really has- so when you put data on it that exceeds it's actual memory, old data will be deleted.”

You can fall into a rabbit hole of dozens of articles and message board posts about this stuff.

The basic way to stay safe is to buy USB flash drives from legitimate sellers and from legitimate brands. And to avoid so-called bargains from Amazon and eBay. You definitely can buy quality/legit stuff from Amazon and eBay but you have to careful of who you buy from and what you are buying.